# Как в переменную из data поместить значение переменной из методов во Vue.js

Tags: javascript, веб-программирование, vue.js

Нужно поместить значение переменной из методов - "num2" в переменную в data - "num". При моей реализации компилятор выдаёт ошибку: "num2 is not defined".

```js
new Vue({
    el: "#app",
    data: {
        money: 0,
        result: false,
        deposit: "",
        percent: "",
        time: "",
        rub: 0,
        currency: "RUB",
        rub_transfer_show: false,
        usd_transfer_show: false,
        currency1: "",
        green: true,
        green2: false,
        hov: true,
        hov2: true,
        plus_money: 0,
        num: num2//в эту переменную нужно поместить значение
    },
    methods: {
        calculation: function(){
            if(this.green == true){
            this.currency1 = this.currency;
            this.result = true;
            this.rub = this.deposit
            for(let i = 0;i<this.time;i++){
                this.rub = Number((this.rub * this.percent / 100) + Number(this.rub) + Number(this.plus_money));
            }
            let res = Math.round(this.rub);
            this.money = res.toLocaleString('ru-RU');
            }
            if(this.green2 == true){
            this.currency1 = this.currency;
            this.result = true;
            this.rub = this.deposit;
            for(let i = 0;i<this.time;i++){
                this.rub = Number((this.deposit * this.percent / 100) + Number(this.rub) + Number(this.plus_money));
                num2 =  Number(i);//вот это значение
            }
            let res = Math.round(this.rub);
            this.money = Math.round(res).toLocaleString('ru-RU');
            }
        },
        h1:function(){
            this.hov = false;
            this.green = true;
            this.hov2 = true;
            this.green2 = false;
        },
        h2:function(){
            this.hov = true;
            this.green = false;
            this.hov2 = false;
            this.green2 = true;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: this.num = num2 - не подходит?

Answer (score 1):

Вам num: num2 в data так писать не надо, потому как num2 надо раньше определить, поэтому в конце метода просто пишете this.num = новое_значение и все,

`data{
    ...
    num: 0
}`